# How to upgrade to PhpStorm 8?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, upgrade

JetBrains recently released PhpStorm 8 but I could not find any information on how to upgrade. I'm currently using PhpStorm 7.

The EAP versions explicitly mentiones that a new folder should be used:

> This build includes a 30-day time-limited license. There is no patch
>   updates available.
>
> **Remember to install .zip & .tar.gz versions into completely empty
>   folder. Do not just unpack over previous version!**
>
> Please note that 8.0 builds use separate settings folder so either
>   automatic or manual import of settings may be required. 3rd party
>   plugins may or may not be compatible with 134.x builds – please ping
>   plugin authors in case of any problems. We gladly offer them our
>   support.

Source: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/phpstorm-8-early-access-program-started/

I don't know if this also applies to the final version? Is there any public info on how to upgrade?

Comment: Just go here: http://download.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-8.0.exe to download the new version without deleting your old PHPStorm. When processing the install, the software will ask you if you want to keep your old settings. I did it this morning, and it works well now.

Comment: This is the best question ever. I'm sure Stackoverflow was build just to get this answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download and install it ;) During the installation you get all information you need and you can import your old settings.

You can download it here: http://download.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-8.0.exe

Comment: The setup asks me to select a version I want to uninstall (my current 7.1.3) - do I have to check that box? What about uninstall silently (checkbox at the bottom)?

Comment: If you want ;) you can install both versions .

Comment: Checked both and it worked as expected. All settings are still in place :)

Comment: To confirm, it can import your old settings on Linux too (I tried on Ubuntu).  Just install it and then delete the directory of the old version.  However, **you should copy your licence key first** - that didn't come across as part of the settings import, so I had to re-enter it!

Comment: Another thing to do on Ubuntu after upgrading - you may need to fix your launcher icon.  To do that, edit `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop` and change the `Exec` and `Icon` lines to reference your new version's path.  (Originally from [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/524924/212629).)

Comment: Still works the same for PhpStorm 9, btw :)

Comment: Re the launcher icon - I found (with PHPStorm 10) that the file I've mentioned above didn't exist.  I fixed the icon by just going to `Tools > Create Desktop Entry` from PHPStorm itself; much easier!

Comment: god knows why the process is so complex. every other application I have I click the update button and it's done. with phpstorm I have to go to the download page, close my current application, then register again...